# Why does the WP8 Tiles example use reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-phone

Use of the new WP8 Tiles uses reflection instead of instantiating and calling the methods directly as shown below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574(v=vs.105).aspx

`Type shellTileType = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone");`

shellTileType.GetMethod("Update").Invoke(tileToUpdate, new Object[] { UpdateTileData });

I'm wondering if there is a specific reason reflection is being used this situation. Is it cause the WP < 7.8 won't have a reference to the ShellTile Type and thus the VM will error? If the VM never accesses this part of the code wouldn't that be good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target your app for one of WP7 or WP8 platfroms.

In WP7 SDK there is no `FlipTileData` class, so you won't be able to compele code wich uses this class.

But you can run your WP7 app on WP8 device, so you can create Wilde Tiles using reflection.
You just need to check the OS version before:

```
private static Version TargetedVersion = new Version(8, 0);
public static bool IsTargetedVersion 
{
   get
     {
       return Environment.OSVersion.Version >= TargetedVersion;
     }
 }
```

Otherwise, if you target your app for WP8 platform only - feel free to use `FlipTileData` and other classes without reflection. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you can find the example.

Answer (score 1):

In WP7 SDK there is no API for these new Tile types, they are only available in WP7.8 and WP8. So if you want to use new tile sizes on WP7.8 devices or in WP7 application running on WP8 device, you have to use reflection.
Of course in WP8 app you can use the API directly with no problems.